# How can i create an autocomplete with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm creating a Django site, on a certain template i added an Ajax form and i would like to add an autocomplete feature, in order to make navigation easier.

My main problem is that the data i should search is a JSON array of objects, while most of the solutions i found work with normal arrays.

Here is what i have now:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Defining the local dataset
        $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/', function(data) {
          console.log(data)
          //Autocomplete
        });
    });
</script>   

<input type="text" id='firstfield' name='input_val'>
```

This is what the data looks like, it's around 700 records; here are the first three:

```
"results": [
        {
            "item": "First",
            "id": "1847",
        },
        {
            "item": "Second",
            "id": "4442",
        },
        {
            "item": "Third",
            "id": "3847",
        }]
```

I need this to be as fast as possible. Is there a JQuery/Ajax native solution for this? Or is there a specific library to do this? Any advice or solution is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Like this? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ Changing the array is simple: `data.results.map(obj => obj.item)` will result in an array of the items.

Comment: Yeah, autocomplete is a valid solution, i just don't understand what to use between typehead and autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [jQuery Typeahead Search](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead) plugin. Just set-up your form to use the proper nesting of classes as seen below.

```js
$(() => {
  //$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/', function(data) {
  let data = {
    "results": [
      { "item": "First",  "id": "1847" },
      { "item": "Second", "id": "4442" },
      { "item": "Third",  "id": "3847" }
    ]
  };
  $('#first-field').typeahead({
    source: {
      data: data.results.map(record => record.item)
    },
    callback: {
      onInit: function($el) {
        console.log(`Typeahead initiated on: ${$el.prop('tagName')}#${$el.attr('id')}`);
      }
    }
  });
  //})
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.11.0/jquery.typeahead.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-typeahead/2.11.0/jquery.typeahead.min.js"></script>
<h1>jQuery Typeahead</h1>
<form>
  <div class="typeahead__container">
    <div class="typeahead__field">
      <div class="typeahead__query">
        <input id="first-field" name="first-field" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="typeahead__button">
        <button type="submit"><i class="typeahead__search-icon"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed Typehead seems a valid solution, but what is the main difference, compared to Jquery Autocomplete? Is one better than the other?

Comment: @Jack022 It's a jQuery plugin (plain and simple) and does not require the additional overhead of jQuery UI. Also, it is less restrictive in terms of style control.

Comment: Thanks! I'm taking a look to the code, and i think i'll go with Typehead. Only thing worrying me a bit is that the last commit to the code is 2 years ago; i'm wondering if it could create any problem with future version of Jquery or any other JS library

Comment: @Jack022 The last commit was less than four months ago: https://github.com/running-coder/jquery-typeahead/blob/master/src/jquery.typeahead.js

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry! Thank you a lot!

Comment: I got confused with this one: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
  <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
            // Defining the local dataset
            $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapi/', function(data) {
              console.log(data)
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
              source: data
            });
            });
        });
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="ui-widget">
          <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
          <input id="tags">
        </div>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery autocomplete() function

Here is the link 
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );

var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure"}
```